# Where did this punycode include come from?

Tags: javascript, .net, visual-studio, google-chrome, punycode

Yesterday I was debugging a standard .Net MVC web application using Visual Studio 2019. I have some javascript behind the view to asynchronously load some dropdown menus using jquery.  The view was basically complete and working but needed a small correction. After correcting a typo I relaunched the view in chrome and it failed to load at all.  The debugging console in chrome showed I had an include as the first line of my js file.  It was the line;

Include { encode } from punycode

I did not put this in my code.  I have never used punycode and do not have it on my machine.
Where did this come from?  Did VS2019 put it there as part of debugging?  Did Chrome?

I am starting to feel paranoid about this appearing for no reason that I can find.

Comment: First load the css and at last js in the page

Comment: Hi LDS.  I greatly appreciate the time and effort that it takes to post here, but I do not think that is the correct answer.  Changing the order won't change the content.

Comment: so sorry ,but it is difficult to say without know the details like the code and js are used ,some times it happens when called a function ,but called later